# Pylab - 'module' object has no attribute 'Figure'

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to use Tkinter to create a view, and therefore I'm also using pylab. My problem is that I get an error saying:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Figure'

and the error comes from this line of code:

```
self.fig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(pylab.figure(), master=self)
```

I'm new to python, so I don't know how to fix this, since the `figure()` should be a part of the pylab library.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**:

Here's the full code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import Style
import pylab
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import cumsum
import matplotlib

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, motspiller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.style = Style()
        self.fig = None
    def setup(self):
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        label = Label(self.parent)
        label.place(x=800, y=50)
        quit_button = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.quit)
        quit_button.place(x=1000, y=450)

        self.fig = FigureCanvasTkAgg(pylab.figure(), master=self)
        self.fig.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.fig.show()
```

Comment: You probably forgot an import, show us your full code

Comment: @Natecat Code has been added

Comment: are you able to run this:  `import pylab; f=pylab.figure()` in your python interpreter?

Comment: Is there any script in the same folder as where you are running this from entitled pylab.py?

Comment: @ballsatballsdotballs nope, the same message appears

Comment: @Natecat No, there is not

Comment: Can you get any method from pylab to run properly? something is wrong with your import I think

Comment: @Natecat I couldn't run the command ballsatballsdotballs suggested either, so I think you're right.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you're unable to run any of the other `pylab` functions then there's a problem with your install. I just ran into a similar error when I installed `matplotlib` and then `pylab`, and it turns out that installing `matplotlib` will *also* install `pylab` for you and that separately installing `pylab` on top of it will cause those exact problems. A simple `pip uninstall pylab` did it for me, since it removed the newly installed `pylab` and let me import the one that came bundled with `matplotlib` instead.

Comment: I had to uninstall both pylab and matplotlib before reinstalling matplotlib.

Comment: I uninstalled pylab and matplotlib, reinstalled matplotlib, and ran pip2 list.  I don't see pylab installed.  I opened python and tried to `import pylab`, but it failed saying `ImortError: No module named lib`