# from pylab import plot

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed python 3.5 on a computer running Scientific Linux 6.5. I have set up a virtual environment, and I have installed `numpy` and `pylab` using `pip` version 8.1.2.

My problem is this, when I try to do the simplest of tasks, i.e. import plot from pylab, I get this:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.1 (default, May 10 2016, 12:41:42) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pylab import plot
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'plot'
>>>
```

Here is some other information:

```
>>> pylab.__version__
'0.1.0'
>>> matplotlib.__version__
'1.5.1'
>>>
```

I don't find any help through Google, and the only question similar to this doesn't seem relevant to me. What is going on?

Comment: try `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` to make sure pyplot can be imported, then try `plt.plot`.

Comment: This solution did work for me, but it didn't clear up the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After coming back over a weekend break and trying again with iPython, I got a different error message, which led to another Google search...

I found the answer here: [Pylab - 'module' object has no attribute 'Figure'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279887/pylab-module-object-has-no-attribute-figure)

My mistake was to think that `pip install pylab` would work as expected!

Installing `pylab` installs `matplotlib`, which apparently also installs `pylab`. This recursion causes the error. For me, uninstalling `pylab` and `matplotlib` and re-installing `matplotlib` alone fixed the error. I hope this helps!